# SQLite - retrieve set of names from the table

Tags: mysql, sql, database, sqlite

I have stored some names and scores in a SQLite Database, as shown in the screenshot.

[image]

Database name: `database`

Table name: `table`

Fields in table Table:

```
* Name

* Score
```

I can retrieve the `name` from the database for the given `score`.

My requirement is, if I give a range value of 10, it should be added to the `score` and I should get the set of `names` in the given range.

For example, if the range value is 10, and the given `score` is 120, I should get the set of `names` between the range 120 to 130.

So, the result should be Mike, Raj and Sams.

How could I make this work? Is there any query? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is this SQLite, MySQL, or both?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure, how about:

```
select name from table 
where score >= @score and score <= (@score + @range)
```

Alternative syntax:

```
select name from table 
where score between @score and (@score + @range)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select * from my_table where score >= start and score <= start + range
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT Name FROM table 
WHERE Score >= @yourScore and Score <= (@yourScore + @delta)
```